# How to read the nodes of xml file in c#, where the xml file is the combination of 2 xml file data?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have combined 2 xml file data into a single xml file, which will be in following syntax

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
<Report>
 <Messages>
  <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
 </Messages>
</Report>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
<Report>
 <Messages>
  <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
</Messages>
</Report>
```

and I want to get the text data from `<Message> </Message>` node.

I have written following usual xml load code to get the details.

```
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Path + "\\result.xml");
```

But I am getting the following error.

**"Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 10, position 3."**

Is the error because of there are two `<?xml` declaration? If so, what is the best way to get all the data within `<Message> </Message>` tag?

Comment: I'd read the file as a `string`, then split it using the the declaration line, then create an `XmlDocument` for each string of the split result.

Comment: You combined two xml files in a string that looks like xml file, but actually is not.

Comment: Instead of fixing reading that invalid file - fix how you write it. I mean - there is no reason to combine 2 xml files this way.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
```

can contain just once for a XML file, at its start.

Please remove these lines from the middle of your result file.

And also please wrap your XML into some root tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
<Root>
<Report>
 <Messages>
  <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
 </Messages>
</Report>
<Report>
 <Messages>
  <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
</Messages>
</Report>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my xml file can have multiple `<?xml>` tag.  How to atleast remove lines starting with `<?xml> ` except first two lines of the document

Comment: You can load xml to a string variable and remove incorrect <?xml> tags using regular expression. And then instead of doc.Load(Path + "\\result.xml"); use doc.LoadXml(yourXmlStringVariable);

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DotNet Fan answer. **Remove the duplicate `<?xml` lines and wrap your elements with a root element**. Here is the code:

```
// read all the lines
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\TestFiles\TextFile1.txt");

var filtered = 
allLines.Take(2).   // take the first two lines i.e. the declaration
Concat(new string[] { "<Root>" }).  // add a Root element start header
Concat(allLines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("<?xml"))). // get all lines that do not start with <?xml
Concat(new string[] { "</Root>" }); // add the end header

string oneXmlFile = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filtered); // join all lines into one string

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(oneXmlFile);   // read the new string as XML
```

This is the XML result file

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
<Root>
  <Report>
    <Messages>
      <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
    </Messages>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Messages>
      <Message>
    My Data
  </Message>
    </Messages>
  </Report>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will reader your xml without errors.  Worked around the duplicates

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string input = "";
            string xml = "";
            while((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!input.StartsWith("<?xml"))
                {
                    xml += input;
                }
            }
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader, settings);
            List<XElement> reports = new List<XElement>();
            while (!xReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xReader.Name != "Report")
                {
                    xReader.ReadToFollowing("Report");
                }
                if (!xReader.EOF)
                {
                    reports.Add((XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(xReader));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\users\Report.xsl"?>
```

xml file has something format error